# Notice on setting a property

Tags: php, properties

I get this notice:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property ReadData_model::$err has
>   no effect

on this line:

```
$this->err{$target . '_db'} = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Sorry, we could not connect to your <strong>' . $target . ' database</strong>. Plese check your entries and try connecting again.</div>';
```

I am actually trying to set a dynamic property.

What does the notice mean and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: show class definitions

Comment: It likely means that `->err` is a virtual property from `__get`. Furthermore that syntax would set an array entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve it like this and it works:

```
$this->{'err_' . $target . '_db'} = 'whatever';
```